# How do I create an object with subvalues without creating a class?

Tags: python, class, oop

I want to create an object, `A`, with `x` and `y` values without creating a class.

```py
#<Code I am looking for goes here.>

print(A.x, A.y)
```

Is there an easy way to do this that I am missing, or is it too hacky?

Comment: Not sure why you are avoiding using a class here. You can use a dictionary if you want it hard coded. A = {'x': value,
'y': value} and then call A['x'], A['y']

Comment: That's not *quite* what I am looking for. To access things from a dictionary, I would use `A['x']` and `A['y']` instead of `A.x` and `A.y`.

Comment: .x has to be a method of A then, which from my understanding requires it to be an object of a class with a method .x

Comment: you need [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to accomplish this would be:

```
import types

A = types.SimpleNamespace(x=5, y=2)
print(A.x, A.y)
```

Comment: This is more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer to this question:

```
A = type('any name', (), {'x': 15, 'y': 23})

print(A.x, A.y)
```

Read more about it [here](https://python.plainenglish.io/creating-a-class-in-python-without-the-class-keyword-67ce84bae22).